# How to create fix duration event in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want to create event in fullcalendar with fix duration. user will able to move the event on timeline but its not allow to change the duration of the event so user can move the event start time on calendar and endtime willl automatically adjust according to the duration or you can save width of the event box will be always same size.

i tried to use the proporty

```
eventDurationEditable : false
```

and I am using fullcalendar-scheduler-4.0.0-beta.2 but its not working as expected

eventDurationEditable : false

user is able to move the event startdatetime but enddatetime remains fix.

any help to solve this issue ?

I also tried property `durationEditable : false`

below is sample code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/resource-timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/timeline/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/resource-common/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/resource-timeline/main.js'></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'resourceTimeline' ],
      now: '2019-02-07',
      editable: true,
      eventDurationEditable: false,
      aspectRatio: 1.8,
      scrollTime: '00:00',
      header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineThreeDays,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
      },
      defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
      views: {
        resourceTimelineThreeDays: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { days: 3 },
          buttonText: '3 days'
        }
      },
      resourceAreaWidth: '30%',
      resourceColumns: [
        {
          labelText: 'Room',
          field: 'title'
        },
        {
          labelText: 'Occupancy',
          field: 'occupancy'
        }
      ],
      resources: [
        { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'green' },
        { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'orange' }

      events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2019-02-07T02:00:00', end: '2019-02-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2019-02-07T05:00:00', end: '2019-02-07T22:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2019-02-06', end: '2019-02-08', title: 'event 3' },

      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To me it looks like a bug. The behaviour is different from when the v3 code is used with the same settings. You'd have to [raise it](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) with the fullcalendar maintainers. Bear in mind that v4 is still in beta so some issues might be expected. The other possibility is that the change in behaviour is intentional - I haven't looked through release notes etc to know if that's the case or not, but perhaps you can research it.

Comment: @ADyson thank for update i saw there is option to stop resizing "eventResizableFromStart: false," but same is not available for from end or for full event.

Comment: I agree that option ought to prevent being able to resize it from the top (which I think might actually be a new feature), but it does not. Maybe that is the bug. Or since it's a beta, maybe the option is there but just not implemented yet. Again you'd have to check with the fullCalendar maintainers - I don't have any involvement in the project.

Comment: Is "resourceTimelineDay" view available in previous version? i dont see any example in previous version

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view there's a "timelineDay" view, yes

Comment: `editable: true, eventStartEditable: true, eventDurationEditable: false`